# How to have different files on different branches and not have them destroy each other on merge?

Tags: git, version-control, heroku, github

I have two branches for a project that I am working on, a public branch being pushed to GitHub and a deploy branch being pushed to Heroku. The deploy branch contains a file with a secret key in it, and the public branch contains files such as LICENSE, README.md, and a secret key generator.

When I make changes to the project, I want to do so on the deploy branch, then when I am ready to push, merge this into the public branch and then push the different branches to their respective remotes. However, when trying to merge deploy into public, it adds the Heroku-specific file and deletes the GitHub-specific files.

I've tried two approaches to prevent this: having the repositories in sync and doing a full merge, but having different .gitignore files, and using .gitattributes files to ignore the aforementioned files while merging. Both seem to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Do a merge --no-commit. Script the checkout of the files you want/delete files you don't want. Now git commit.

```
git merge --no-commit origin/my-branch
git checkout --theirs License.txt
rm super-secret-key.txt
git commit
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should rethink your workflow. If you really need to keep something secret in the git repository, then it would be probably better to work on public branch, and merge that to the deploy branch.

I don't understand what the "deletes the GitHub-specific files." part means though, what causes the deletion of those files?

Comment: The public branch has the readme, etc., and the deploy branch does not. When I merge deploy into public, it removes those files.